# join multiple tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to join multiple table using MySQL. I have done some coding  which has given below.

```
select u.user_name
, u.user_id
, p.colg_name
, r.role
, d.dept_name 
from db_user u 
 JOIN db_profile p 
ON u.colg_id=p.profile_id 
 JOIN db_role r 
  ON u.role_id = r.role_id 
 JOIN db_department d 
  ON u.dept_id = d.dept_id 
WHERE u.user_type = 3
 AND u.role_id != 0
 AND u.colg_id != 0
 ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
```

Here my problem is if `db_user` table has `dept_id` column value is `0` this query is not working. Here my requirement is if in `db_user` table `dept_id` column value is `0` it will not match with `db_department` table and fetch all other data if `dept_id` values are other than `0` then it will match with `db_department` table and fetch all data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the usage of php here, it is a sql only issue. I suggest you remove the `php` tag from your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join. That will allow your query to work even if there are no corresponding records (dept_id = 0) in the table that is left joined.

```
select u.user_name
, u.user_id
, p.colg_name
, r.role
, IFNULL(d.dept_name,'no department') AS dept_name
from db_user u 
 JOIN db_profile p 
ON u.colg_id=p.profile_id 
 JOIN db_role r 
  ON u.role_id = r.role_id 
 LEFT JOIN db_department d 
  ON u.dept_id = d.dept_id 
WHERE u.user_type = 3
 AND u.role_id != 0
 AND u.colg_id != 0
 ORDER BY u.user_id DESC
```